# How to just output the correct result with key and value?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json as below:

```
[
    {
      "AvailabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1a",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "value1",
          "Key": "key1"
        },
        {
          "Value": "value2",
          "Key": "key2"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
          "AvailabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1a",
          "Tags": [
            {
              "Value": "value3",
              "Key": "key3"
            },
            {
              "Value": "value4",
              "Key": "key4"
            }
          ],
        },
]
```

when i input key and value from keyboard. I want to just output the correct result with the key and value through the jq option.

Example: I input Key:value is key3:value3. My desire:

```
{
      "AvailabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1a",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "value3",
          "Key": "key3"
        },
        {
          "Value": "value4",
          "Key": "key4"
        }
      ],
}
```

Comment: Can you describe more what actual output you are expecting ?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. How do you expect to "input key and value from keyboard"?  What is the "correct result"? What have you tried?

Comment: @ParvezKazi I have 100 volume (EBS) in aws. each volume (EBS), I tagged tags (include key:value). When I input correct key and value of a tag then output correct result of this volume (EBS).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using aws cli to fetch ebs volume details, you can use the filters properties of aws cli to filter out results of your query.
Here you can use below :
`aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=tag-key,Values="key3" Name=tag-value,Values="value3"`

Find more help at:
`aws ec2 describe-volumes help`

I think this will be easier than filtering using jq.

Answer (score 1):

Use select to filter the array under Tags:

```
jq '.[].Tags | select((.[].Key == "key3") and (.[].Value="value3"))  ' < file.json
```

Together with reading the key and value from the stdin:

```
echo key3 value3 | (
    read key value
    k=$key v=$value jq ".[].Tags
        | select((.[].Key == env.k) and (.[].Value=env.v))
    " < file.json)
```